# custom DNS on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dns

Is it possible to change what DNS server the phone is using?  I would like to write a web browser that can access OpenNIC web sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capability to configure this isn't exposed in the current 3rd party app SDK at the moment.